# Downloading a file following all redirects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser

I need to be able to follow an URL until all redirects are finally over and a file download commences. Think for example of Sourceforge download URLs. I am not talking just about plain HTTP redirects but Javascript too.

I am constrained to pure managed WinForms NET 2.0. I have been using `WebClient` successfully until this redirect problem came up. I thought I could simply use `WebBrowser`, navigate to an URL and wait. But I need to do the download entirely without user intervention and additionally monitor the download progress. There appears to be a `FileDownload` event but it only seems to be raised after a successful download is complete.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to automatically accept EULA as well (like what you need when downloading Reflector addins)?

Comment: Sarcasm? Am I asking too much? No, of course I do not want to accept any EULAs. EULAs require manual user intervention. I was only asking for redirects.

Comment: yes, evaluating JS redirects is really too much. JS redirect is not something that is guaranteed to be called at some specified time or event. It may wait N seconds, may check cookies, may expect user interaction etc. Consider that there might be redirects through Flash, Silverlight etc. Consider that the redirect can be triggered in JS by some event like page being fully loaded, you'll need to emulate that. You'll see that you are asking for implementing an almost complete browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is not possible since you ruled out the [native download manager APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (C# wrapper [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx)).

Why you rule out native code? The Webbrowser class itself is not pure managed either. It is built on top of native IE APIs.

Comment: Thanks! The thing is that I need something that can be fully integrated with my app, linked and/or obfuscated. I found the wrapper you mention myself and I was under the impression it was written in C++ therefore completely unsuitable. Other than this I noticed it required `regsvr32` registration which is also a no-no. So, let me put it this way. I need a managed + interop solution (no mixed mode assemblies). I will take a second look at it.

Comment: it requires regsvr for something else I think. The sample is not registering for the download manager otherwise it would take over IE's download.